# No mapping exists from object type System.Net.Sockets.SocketException to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, socketexception

I have created a webpage that is able to post some value to other website and get the response from that page as a HTML document. After I get the response from the other website, I am parsing it with the help of HTMLAgilityPack and getting the required data. This data is then saved in a SQL Server database.  This all scenario is working fine in development environment but after deployment at the server, it is giving the above error.

Here is the function where I am getting the data from other website, parsing and saving it.

```
public static string FetchDataFromWebsite(string uId)
    {
        string url = "http://demourl.aspx";
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "some data to post";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; sv-SE; rv:1.9.1b2) Gecko/20081201 Firefox/3.1b2";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        var response = myRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(result);

        var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='GridView1']");
        if (table != null)
        {
            var tr = table.SelectSingleNode("//tr[2]");
            string[] trData = new string[12];

            int rowCount = 0;

            foreach (HtmlNode td in tr.SelectNodes("//td"))
            {
                rowCount++;
                if (rowCount > 3 && rowCount < 16)
                {

                    trData[rowCount - 4] = td.InnerText;
                }
                if (rowCount >= 16)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            saveDataInDatabase(trData);
            return "Cheers! data saved.";

        }
        else
        {

            var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='lbmessage']");
            string message = span.InnerText;
            InsertErrorLog(uId, message);
            return "No data found";
        }
}
```

Where I am doing some wrong thing, which is giving me this error. May be the above error is due to some server settings, please help to modify the settings. By the way, I am using IIS 7.5 as the server and the server OS is Windows server 2008 R2.

waiting for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this problem. It was actually occurring due to improper datatype conversion at the SQL Server end. By mistake i was passing ex.innerException into a field of datatype nvarchar. This is why the exception was occurring.

Hence the final point here is: if you try to pass some parameter from any language to SQL server, you must make sure that the datatypes are matching or interoprable with each other.